# Is past perfect justified in this case?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

> I can confirm the lathe cut records were included (parts 1-7). Apologies for the confusion, that shipping notification is a new automatic thing. Sorry again that you **hadn't received** them yet.

I don't think past perfect is justified because he is still feeling sorry, even the records have been shipped shipped, so I think present perfect would be a better choice.

Am I right?

Comment: If there were no "yet" in that statement, Past Perfect would be OK.  With "yet" it implies "now" and Present would be better.  As it stands, the person saying they are sorry, are actually sorry about the past fact, hence the choice of Past Perfect, I think.

Comment: Speaker could be alluding with "yet" to a complaint "We haven't received the records yet". One might call it the "empathetic past perfect". It's not actually an apology for the non-delivery but for the confusion caused by a spurious shipping notice--which took place in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

If the person is still without the records, the present perfect is the way to go:

**Sorry again that you haven't received them yet.**

If they are currently in possession of the records, and you want to retroactively apologize for their not having received them by some previous date X, I would simply say:

**Sorry again that you didn't receive them on time.**

Answer (score 0):

present perfect or simple past.  Hadn't received them is past perfect which is actions that are over and will not occur again. He was trying to say "sorry you hadn't received them by the time you expected to."